# Input is ended with an end-of-file character (EOF) in C, C++ and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

I start learning ***Python*** language a few days ago. My skill in ***python*** is not too much high. But whatever I learn, I want to solve **UVA Online Judge** problem

When I try to solve the problem **272 TEX Quotes** I faces a problem to terminate loop when user input is given by end-of-file.

Check my (100% logic solved) code in python **(except while loop terminate)**

```
flag = True;

while True: #I want That loop is terminated when getting EOF
    txt = input()

    for var in txt:
        if var == '"':
            if flag:
                print("``", end='')
            else:
                print("''", end='')
            flag = not flag
        else:
            print(var, end='')

    print(end='\n')
```

Check my accepted solved code in ***C*** it's terminate loop with end-of-file which is given by **Ctrl** + **Z**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int flag = 1;
    char txt;

    while((txt = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(txt == '"'){
            if(flag)
                printf("``");
            else
                printf("''");

            flag = !flag;
        }else
            putchar(txt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, ***C++***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char txt;
    bool flag = true;

    while((txt = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(txt == '"'){
            if(flag)
                cout << "``";
            else
                cout << "''";

            flag = !flag;
        }else
            cout << txt;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int txt` otherwise `EOF` handling is messy.

Comment: When you provide EOF to your program (e.g., via `^D`), `input()` will raise an `EOFError` and the program will exit. What's the problem?

Comment: Isn't there a different forum for code reviews?

Comment: It's alright in c or c++ code datatype for int txt

Because if you write the following code like
printf("%d",getchar());
And then if you give the input from the keyboard A You should see 65 which is ASCII value of the A or if you give CTRL-Z then see -1.

And also python doesn't give the datatype so that there is no problem with that #coderredoc

Comment: Just because you replace all the calls to `printf` with `cout` doesn't mean you're really writing C++ code. Come on now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOF while input raises EOFError so you can use try … except block with break statement:

```
flag = True;

while True: #I want That loop is terminated when getting EOF
    try:
        txt = input()

        for var in txt:
            if var == '"':
                if flag:
                    print("``", end='')
                else:
                    print("''", end='')
                flag = not flag
            else:
                print(var, end='')

        print(end='\n')
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your Answer. And I will also know you that the solved answer is Accepted by UVA Online judge. But One thing Tell me, please is it possible like c or c++ doing the thing in while loop #Amaro_Vita

Comment: Hello, #Amaro_Vita I am still waiting for you. for your next better efficient solving answer what is told by me in the comment above